# How to extract AuthorityKeyIdentifier from X509 Certificate

Tags: java, scala, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I am trying to extract the AuthorityKeyIdentifier (OID:2.5.29.35) form a valid certificate using bouncycastle in scala.

```
case class ExtendedX509Certificate(x509Certificate : X509Certificate) {
  
  object OID {
    val SUBJECT_KEY_IDENTIFIER : String = "2.5.29.14"
    val AUTHORITY_KEY_IDENTIFIER : String = "2.5.29.35"
  }
```

I figured out how to do it for the `SubjectKeyIdentifier`:

```
  def getSubjectKeyIdentifier : SubjectKeyIdentifier = {
      val encoding : Array[Byte] = x509Certificate.getExtensionValue(OID.SUBJECT_KEY_IDENTIFIER)
      SubjectKeyIdentifier.getInstance(encoding)
  }
```

However, similar code for the `AuthorityKeyIdentifier` does not work:

```
  def getAuthorityKeyIdentifier : AuthorityKeyIdentifier = {
      val encoding : Array[Byte] =   x509Certificate.getExtensionValue(OID.AUTHORITY_KEY_IDENTIFIER)
      AuthorityKeyIdentifier.getInstance(encoding)
  }
}
```

and crashes with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString
```

Why doesn´t the same approach work for the two identifiers and how do I make it work?

I am testing using:

```
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
```

and I parse that file using:

```
def fromPEMString(cert: String, addWrapperLines: Boolean = false): Option[ExtendedX509Certificate] = {
    val PEMString = {
      if (addWrapperLines) {
        val startLine = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
        val endLine = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
        s"$startLine\n$cert\n$endLine"
      } else {
        cert
      }

    }
    Option(X509CertUtils.parse(PEMString)) match {
      case Some(parsed) => Some(ExtendedX509Certificate(cert, parsed))
      case None => None
    }
  }
```

Comment: I try to replicate your code [here](https://github.com/cric96/certificate-scala-example]) and it seems to work (Scala 2.13, JDK 15, and bouncycastle 1.68). What certificate do you pass to Extendedx509Certificate? Tips: in Scala, it is usual to use pimp my library (a.k.a type enrichment) when you want to create an extended version of some class, a reference to implement could be found [here](http://blog.rcard.in/jvm/programming/design-pattern/2019/12/15/pimp-my-library-pattern.html#:~:text=answer%20this%20problem.-,Scala,using%20any%20form%20of%20inheritance.)

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi it still fails for me. I did adopt your versions however, I do not use your self signed certificate but use the one I edited into the end of the question. You need `"com.nimbusds"     % "nimbus-jose-jwt" % "9.8.1",` as a dependency if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the mistake.

In

```
AuthorityKeyIdentifier.getInstance(encoding)
```

You should pass a byte array arranged in ASN.1 octet string. So, a way to do that could be:

```
AuthorityKeyIdentifier.getInstance(ASN1OctetString.getInstance(encoding).getOctets)
```

I hope that I helped you.

Comment: Yes this does not crash anymore. Any Idea on why the two different attributes differ in accessing them?